# sql number of times computer is active

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to make a query on a postgresql 9.1 table with the two relevant columns being:

```
occurred - timestamp with timezone
computer - varchar
```

Assume that the table covers a 24 hour period from midnight to midnight and i need to get a 24 length list where each element is the count of rows that *one* computer had during that hour of the day. I will have the computer name for the `WHERE` clause.

Here is my sql so far:

```
select extract(hour from occurred) as hr, count(where computer = "computername") 
    from tablename group by extract(hour from occurred) order by 1
```

Comment: We don't like 'gimme the codez' non-questions. You have to show you've put in some effort yourself before we'll try to help. That being said, read up about SQL aggregate functions, particularly count(): http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-aggregate.html

Comment: Sorry I just need a minor amount of sql in my project and I obviously have been making solo attempts but so far have came nowhere close. Just thought this would be a quick help... and believe me the docs are the first place I went.

Comment: Please show us the solo attempts you have been making. Giving potential answerers a jumping-off point will improve the likelihood that we can solve your problem. Even if you don't think your attempts are anywhere close, it may still be useful (and it demonstrates a good faith effort on your part)

Comment: @Kevin Edited with my sql attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to tighten this query up so that you only count the data for a single day at a time, rather than generating counts for the number of times the computer was active between, say, 05:00 and 06:00 on all daya when it was recorded as being active.  You will also need to worry about generating zero counts for hours when the computer was not recorded as being active at all.  However, we can modify your SQL into something that might more or less work:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(HOUR FROM occurred) AS hr, COUNT(*) AS count
  FROM tablename
 WHERE computer = 'computername'  -- corrected (" ⟶ ')
 GROUP BY EXTRACT(HOUR FROM occurred)
 ORDER BY 1
```

Syntactically, that is correct (I think).

This is one of many possible ways of defining a specific date.  You might need to specify the time zone to get more reliable data.

```
SELECT EXTRACT(HOUR FROM occurred) AS hr, COUNT(*) AS count
  FROM tablename
 WHERE computer = 'computername'  -- corrected (" ⟶ ')
   AND occurred >= TIMESTAMP '2012-08-02 00:00:00'
   AND occurred <  TIMESTAMP '2012-08-03 00:00:00'
 GROUP BY EXTRACT(HOUR FROM occurred)
 ORDER BY 1
```

Generating data for all 24 hours even if there is no activity for the computer during some of those hours is harder.  You'd create a list of 24 hours somehow (there are a variety of possible methods; I'm not sure which is most appropriate in PostgreSQL), and then outer join that with the projection of the computer activity records:

```
SELECT hh, COUNT(*)
  FROM hours_00_to_23 AS h
  LEFT JOIN
       (SELECT EXTRACT(HOUR FROM occurred) AS hh
          FROM tablename
         WHERE computer = 'computername'  -- corrected (" ⟶ ')
       ) AS a
    ON a.hh = h.hh
 GROUP BY hh
 ORDER BY hh
```

You can combine the criteria to get the data for a specific date, etc.

*Warning: No DBMS was plagued by attempts to run any of the postulated SQL in this answer!*

> I have no clue how to fix the third one, getting relation "hours_00_to_23" does not exist on the second line.

You need to create a (temporary?) table containing a column `hh` of the appropriate type (that is itself an interesting quesion — what is the correct type) populated with values 0 through 23.  A possible nasty brute force solution (with debatable type) is:

```
CREATE TABLE hours_00_to_23(hh INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT INTO hours_00_to_23 VALUES(0);
INSERT INTO hours_00_to_23 VALUES(1);
...
INSERT INTO hours_00_to_23 VALUES(23);
```

There are probably other ways to achieve the same effect.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan! The first two work if I use single quotes around computername. However, I have no clue how to fix the third one, getting relation "hours_00_to_23" does not exist on the second line.

Answer (score 2):

Your query is a fine starting point.  You need to pivot the values.  Here is one way:

```
select computer,
       sum(case when hr = 1 then cnt else 0 end) as hr01,
       sum(case when hr = 2 then cnt else 0 end) as hr02,
       sum(case when hr = 3 then cnt else 0 end) as hr03,
       ...
       sum(case when hr = 24 then cnt else 0 end) as hr24
from (select computer, extract(hour from occurred) as hr, count(*) as cnt 
      from tablename
      group by computer extract(hour from occurred
     ) t
group by computer
```

(Actually, I forgot if hour goes from 0 to 23 or 1 to 24.)

This creates a table for each computer with the count by hour in separate columns.

Comment: On a 24-hour clock, it's 0 to 23.